# Want to connect to MQ using IBM MQ series -Not JMS. My app will be deployed on WAS and the Q Manager is on anther Server. How do I pass conn Param?

Tags: websphere, ibm-mq

```
    using IBM.WMQ;
    using System;
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Text;
    
    namespace MQTest
    {
        class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
    
    
            {
                string strQueueManagerName = "QM";
                string strChannelName = "CHANNEL1";
                string strQueueName = "QUEUE1";
                string strServerName = "127.0.0.1";
                int intPort = 1414;
                string strMsg = "Hello IBM, this is a message";

                MQEnvironment.SSLCipherSpec = "TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256";

    
                Hashtable queueProperties = new Hashtable
                {
                    { MQC.HOST_NAME_PROPERTY, strServerName },
                    { MQC.CHANNEL_PROPERTY, strChannelName },
                    { MQC.PORT_PROPERTY, intPort },
                    { MQC.TRANSPORT_PROPERTY, MQC.TRANSPORT_MQSERIES_MANAGED }
                };
    
                //Set Username
                //MQEnvironment.UserId = "User";
    
                //Set Passowrd
                //MQEnvironment.Password = "123";
    
                //Define a Queue Manager
                try
                {
                    MQQueueManager myQM = new MQQueueManager(strQueueManagerName, queueProperties);
    
                    //Define a Message
                    MQMessage queueMessage = new MQMessage();
                    queueMessage.Format = MQC.MQFMT_STRING;
                    queueMessage.CharacterSet = Encoding.UTF8.CodePage;
                    queueMessage.Write(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(strMsg));
    
                    //Define a Queue
                    var queue = myQM.AccessQueue
                        (strQueueName, MQC.MQOO_OUTPUT + MQC.MQOO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING);
                    MQPutMessageOptions queuePutMessageOptions = new MQPutMessageOptions();
                    queue.Put(queueMessage, queuePutMessageOptions);
                    queue.Close();
                    Console.WriteLine("Success");
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                }
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
```

> Any info on how can i pass truststore and keystore path to my applicaiton. As my Applicaiton is going to be hosted on WAS (Web App Server) and the MQ is deployed on some remote machine. How I can pass the SSL credentional into my App to talk with MQ.
> Any pointers or clarifications would be much appreciated.

```
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=keystore.ks -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=x
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=keystore.ks -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=x
```

Comment: Not sure if I understood you correctly. See [Java virtual machine custom properties](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/was/9.0.5?topic=jvm-java-virtual-machine-custom-properties) for how to set Java system properties. But from my experience it is better to configure this with [Associating a Secure Sockets Layer configuration dynamically with an outbound protocol and remote secure endpoint](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/was/9.0.5?topic=csc-associating-ssl-configuration-dynamically-outbound-protocol-remote-secure-endpoint).

Comment: You should use WebSphere MQ provider that is included in WebSphere and configure correctly connection factories and queues via console - https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/was-nd/8.5.5?topic=settings-websphere-mq-messaging-provider-connection-factory There is no point of hardcoding these values in the apps deployed on WebSphere, and you should also not change ssl settings directly but use SSL configurations from WAS,

Answer (score 0):

I'm confused by what you have listed.  You are showing C# .NET code but are asking about Java (not JMS) and WAS.

First, do NOT mix the MQEnvironment class with using a HashTable with MQ connection information.  And don't use MQEnvironment class as it is not thread safe.

Basic information:

- Java uses JKS-type (.jks) keystore, whereas MQ used CMS-type (.kdb)
  keystore.
- With SSL/TLS enabled on a channel, authenticating the queue manager with a truststore is always required.
- For "mutual authentication" (optional), a keystore is also required with your private certificate include.
- Java uses CipherSuite whereas MQ uses CipherSpec.  See [TLS CipherSpecs and CipherSuites](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/9.1?topic=jms-tls-cipherspecs-ciphersuites-in-mq-classes) for more information and pay attention to what JVM you are using.
- Depending on your JVM, you will probably want to set the JVM environment variable of com.ibm.mq.cfg.useIBMCipherMappings to either true or false (true for IBM JRE otherwise false).

Below is the connect() method from the MyMQ class of the open source project called [Universal File Mover](https://capitalware.com/ufm_overview.html) (UFM):

```
public void connect() throws MQException, MalformedURLException, ClassNotFoundException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, Exception
{
   UFM.logger.debug("Attempting to connect to queue manager '"+mqo.qMgrName+"'");
   MQException.log = null;

   if (mqo.channelName != null)
   {
      Hashtable<String,Object> mqht = new Hashtable<String,Object>();

      mqht.put(CMQC.CHANNEL_PROPERTY, mqo.channelName);
      mqht.put(CMQC.HOST_NAME_PROPERTY, mqo.hostname);
      mqht.put(CMQC.PORT_PROPERTY, new Integer(mqo.port));

      if (mqo.userID != null)
         mqht.put(CMQC.USER_ID_PROPERTY, mqo.userID);

      if (mqo.password != null)
         mqht.put(CMQC.PASSWORD_PROPERTY, mqo.password);

      /*
       * SSL
       */
      if (mqo.cipherSuiteName != null)
         mqht.put(CMQC.SSL_CIPHER_SUITE_PROPERTY, mqo.cipherSuiteName);

      if (mqo.distinguishedName != null)
         mqht.put(CMQC.SSL_PEER_NAME_PROPERTY, mqo.distinguishedName);

      if (mqo.trustedStore != null)
         System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", mqo.trustedStore);

      if (mqo.trustedStorePasswd != null)
         System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", mqo.trustedStorePasswd);

      if (mqo.keyStore != null)
         System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", mqo.keyStore);

      if (mqo.keyStorePasswd != null)
         System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", mqo.keyStorePasswd);

      if ( ((mqo.ldapServer != null)) && (mqo.ldapServerPort != 0) )
      {
         LDAPCertStoreParameters ldapcsparms = new LDAPCertStoreParameters(mqo.ldapServer, mqo.ldapServerPort);
         CertStore cs = CertStore.getInstance("LDAP", ldapcsparms);
         ArrayList al = new ArrayList();
         al.add(cs);
         mqht.put(CMQC.SSL_CERT_STORE_PROPERTY, al);
      }

      Enumeration<String> names = mqht.keys();
      String key;
      while(names.hasMoreElements())
      {
         key = (String) names.nextElement();

         if (CMQC.PASSWORD_PROPERTY.equalsIgnoreCase(key))
         {
            String pwd = (String)mqht.get(key);
            UFM.logger.info("connect() " + key + " length is '" + (pwd == null?"null":pwd.length()+"") +"'");
         }
         else
            UFM.logger.info("connect() " + key + "='" + mqht.get(key)+"'");
      }

      _qMgr = new MQQueueManager(mqo.qMgrName, mqht);

      UFM.logger.info("Successfully connected to " + mqo.qMgrName + " using " + mqo.channelName + " and " + mqo.hostname+"("+mqo.port+")");
   }
   else if (mqo.CCDTFile != null)
   {
      String trustedStore = System.getenv("MQSSLKEYR");
      if (trustedStore != null)
         System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", trustedStore + ".jks");

      File file = new File(mqo.CCDTFile);
      URL url = file.toURL();

      if (mqo.userID != null)
      {
         Hashtable<String,Object> mqht = new Hashtable<String,Object>();

         mqht.put(CMQC.USER_ID_PROPERTY, mqo.userID);

         if (mqo.password != null)
            mqht.put(CMQC.PASSWORD_PROPERTY, mqo.password);

         _qMgr = new MQQueueManager(mqo.qMgrName, mqht, url);

         UFM.logger.info("Successfully connected to " + mqo.qMgrName + " using " + mqo.CCDTFile + " with UserID");
      }
      else
      {
         _qMgr = new MQQueueManager(mqo.qMgrName, url);

         UFM.logger.info("Successfully connected to " + mqo.qMgrName + " using " + mqo.CCDTFile);
      }
   }
   else
   {
      _qMgr = new MQQueueManager(mqo.qMgrName);

      UFM.logger.info("Successfully connected to " + mqo.qMgrName);
   }
}
```